# Convert Latex code to Html

Tags: overleaf, conversion, html

How to Convert Latex code to HTML in nodejs?
Is it possible? or is there any other way to build pdf and build HTML code using same code?

Comment: See the [lwarp](https://ctan.org/pkg/lwarp) package documentation and other tools therein.

Comment: @Stephen How does `lwarp` compare to `tex4ht`?

Comment: I have only used lwarp. So I can't make the comparison.@AlanMunn

Comment: @AlanMunn I've used both `TeX4ht` (majority) and `lwarp` (few times), and my experience, both are entirely different and both have own interpreters, just my opinion